# image-block and title-block are not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I have a responsive problem on my Wordpress website. When my website is on fullscreen, the products are centered (http://prnt.sc/et1k5q). But when you put it smaller the products are no longer in the middle (http://prnt.sc/et1klx). I'm using "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-centered" for this.
The products are not just an image, but an "image-block" and "title-block".

What do I need to change?

*The template is using bootstrap

Comment: Please check responsiveness by inspecting it and not by resizing the window sometimes the window size won't be a proper device size. And the  window size looks like resolution with  ratio 1:1 or a square.

Comment: I think the size doesn't matter, because on a smartphone I have the same problem: http://prnt.sc/ethnnl

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0 auto;` and check it with both the blocks.

Comment: I already found this solution and set it in, but it don't work...

Answer (score 1):

Just add another class 'text-center' and it will center align things.

Comment: After "image-block" and "title-block"?

Comment: Add on the parent div I.e. on col-xs-12 class div.